# How do I make this log curve an actual curve?

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve

I am trying to fit a natural log curve to my 2d data in python. I fit a curve and graphed it and all, the only problem is that matplotlib just connects the dots, but doesn't "curve" it. How do I do this? My code is here:

```
voltage2 = np.array([0., .1, .2, .5, .8, 1., 1.3])
current2 = np.array([0., .14, .16, .2, .24, .26, .3])

def lnfunct(x, m, h, k):
    return m * np.log(x + h) + k

ws2, cov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(lnfunct, voltage2[1:], current2[1:])

def predictlncurrent(voltage, parameters):
    current = parameters[0] * np.log(voltage[1:] + parameters[1]) + parameters[2]
    return current

predictedlncurrent = predictlncurrent(voltage2, ws2)
predictedlncurrent = np.insert(predictedlncurrent, 0, 0.)

plt.scatter(voltage2, current2, color='g')
plt.plot(voltage2, predictedlncurrent, color='b')
plt.xlabel('Voltage')
plt.ylabel('1 / Current')
plt.suptitle('Voltage vs. 1 / Current with Best Fit Natural Logarithmic Curve (Non-Ohmic)')
```

You really don't need all that, but at least you could see my variables and references. The main part is the plt section. How do I make this a curve without changing my values?

Comment: Most plotting software goes about plotting curves by sampling a bunch of evenly-spaced points and then connecting them with (usually short) line segments (taking for granted that the curve in question is differentiable, if not continuous).

Answer (score 2):

As [Jack Maney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/554546/jack-maney) says the trick is to plot a lot of points (close together) to see the curve. Something like that:

```
x = np.linspace(-0.2, 1.5, 500) # We create 500 in the area of interest
y = lnfunct(x, ws2[0], ws2[1], ws2[2]) # We adjusted for those 500 points

plt.scatter(voltage2, current2, color='g')
plt.plot(x, y, '--', color='r')
```

[image]

You are not adjusting from the first point, that is why it is left alone, far from the adjustment.